# bars not proportional to value - matplotlib bar chart

Tags: matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib and am trying to plot a bar chart using pyplot. Instead of getting a plot where the height of bar represents the value, I am getting bars that are linearly increasing in height while their values are displayed on the y-axis as labels.

```
payment_modes = ['Q', 'NO', 'A', 'C', 'P', 'E', 'D']
l1=[]
l2=[]
for i in payment_modes:
    l.append(str(len(df[df['PMODE_FEB18']==i])))
# here l = ['33906', '37997', '815', '4350', '893', '98', '6']
plt.figure()
plt.bar(range(7),l)
```

This is what I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you seem to be feeding `bar` with strings, not with numerical quantities. If you instead use the actual numerical quantities, `bar` will behave as you would expect:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [33906, 37997, 815, 4350, 893, 98, 6]

plt.figure()
plt.bar(range(7),l)
plt.show()
```

gives

[image]